# Save Dynamic radio button clicked data to database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a generated array of radio buttons based on user selects the data say if my database table has 10 rows then 10 groups of radio buttons are created.

My problem is I need to save the clicked radio button values along with the text box data which is next to the radio button on button click.

The below is the server side query to fetch the data from db and create the rows along with the radio button group and name of each in one text box.

What needs to be done is on click on button I need a query to save only radio button clicked val and all the text box val to be saved in db table as they are dynamically generated i have zero clue how to save then small help would be more help full for me.

```
int numberofrow1 = 0;
int numberofrow2 = 0;

DDccccc = DDccccc.SelectedValue;// store it in some variable;
string htmlStr = "";
using (MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(constr))
{
    string oString = "Select * from xxxxxxxxx WHERE xxxxxx=@cccc  order by xxxxxxxxxxx ASC";
    MySqlCommand oCmd = new MySqlCommand(oString, myConnection);
    oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cccc", DDccccc);

    myConnection.Open();
    using (MySqlDataReader oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (oReader == null || !oReader.HasRows)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "alert", "alert('xxxxxxx')", true);
        }
        else
        {
            while (oReader.Read())
            {
                string Name = oReader["xxxxxxxxxx"].ToString();
                htmlStr += "<tr><td><input type='text' value='" + Name + "'/></td><td><input type='radio' name='Present" + numberofrow++ + "' value='Present'></td><td><input type='radio' name='Present" + numberofrow1++ + "' value='Absent'></td><td><input type='radio' name='Present" + numberofrow2++ + "' value='Leave'></td></tr>";
            }
        }
        myConnection.Close();
    }
}
LIST.InnerHtml = htmlStr;
```

Comment: I guess things would be a lot easier for you if you used [server-side databound controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7k30eyz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) instead of emitting literal html. It would allow you to simply register an according event handler for the desired action.

Comment: @Filburt thanks for the reply but am not sure how to do that and the radio button are dynimically created that is makin me more complex

Comment: The [RadioButtonList class documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) has a lot of how-to examples which will show you how to bind the result of your database query to your RadioButtonList control.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var val = Request.Form["Present1"]
```

**Edit**

If you don't have server id for any control then still you can access there values (as far as they are input). You can access there values using `Form` collection. To get all checkbox values in an array, I presume you have saved number of records in `oReader` somewhere in `int totalRecords`. So you can use following code to access those values as below.

```
List<string> chkValues = new List<string>();
for( int i = 1; i <= totalRecords; i++)
{
    chkValues.Add(Request.Form["Present"+i]);
}
```

Comment: Don't you wanna elaborate a bit on your answer.

Comment: yes that would be help full coz i wana know how to save array of radio button data to be stored

Comment: exactly was looking  for some thing like this thanks alot if u dont mind i need the same query to be elobeated a bit if u can update the query to a db query that would be more help full for me

Comment: @Imad Hi imad sorry for the late reply are you free !!

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can try this : add radio button along with their id and runat='server' so we can easily able to find controls on .cs file :

`<input type='radio' name='Present1' value='Present' runat="server" id="Present1">`

and to find control on any event such like button click event :

```
   `protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var contorl = Page.FindControl("Present1");
    }`
```